# Find an item match between two lists using boolean and create dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to create a data structure to store hostname and amount of this particular device. In list total_switches i have device features for several devices installed in the network. In list n3400_models i have switch family models. I pretend to match installed switch features against switch family models and if matching start a dictionary using key as one of: `n34180yc,n3464c,n3432ds,n3408s` and for value a list of matching hostnames `(h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,h7,h8,h9)` and amounts of the total matching for a particular switch family model.

the code for python 3 i´m using is below but is not working since it doesn't create a value list, i.e {'n34180yc': ['h1','h5','h9'].....}

```
h1 = ("h1","20MB","16GB","1RU",12)
h2 = ("h2","22MB","16GB","2RU",22)
h3 = ("h3","70MB","-","1RU",12)
h4 = ("h4","70MB","-","4RU",22)
h5 = ("h5","20MB","16GB","1RU",12)
h6 = ("h6","22MB","16GB","2RU",22)
h7 = ("h7","70MB","-","1RU",12)
h8 = ("h8","70MB","-","4RU",22)
h9 = ("h9","20MB","16GB","1RU",12)

total_switches = [h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,h7,h8,h9]

n34180yc = ('n34180yc','20MB','16GB','1RU')
n3464c = ('n3464c','22MB','16GB','2RU')
n3432ds = ('n3432ds','70MB','-','1RU')
n3408s = ('n3408s','70MB','-','4RU')

n3400_models = [n34180yc,n3464c,n3432ds,n3408s]

inventory = {}
for switch in n3400_models:
    for feature in total_switches:
        if switch[1:4] == feature[1:4]:
            inventory[switch[0]] = feature[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```py
from itertools import groupby

inventory=dict([(k, list(v)) for k,v in groupby(sorted(total_switches,key=lambda x: x[1:4]), lambda x: x[1:4]) if k in n3400_models])
```

Outputs:

```py
{('70MB', '-', '1RU'): [('h3', '70MB', '-', '1RU', 12), ('h7', '70MB', '-', '1RU', 12)], ('70MB', '-', '4RU'): [('h4', '70MB', '-', '4RU', 22), ('h8', '70MB', '-', '4RU', 22)]}
```

Comment: a little bit advanced for me, i just wanted to know what code line follows to my code in order to populate the value list